# What's the easiest way to comply with open source licenses?

Tags: java, licensing, web-applications

I'm really confused by all the open source licensing details like *"I wrote a web application, which should run on a computer not owned by me. My software uses the library/language xxx. Is this considered a software redistribution of xxx?"*.

Looking at the first four pieces of used software reveals four different licenses (MIT, BSD, Apache, Apache/Eclipse dual). It looks like all of them require about the same, i.e., list them and link to their license.

So I thought I could simplify my life by simply voluntarily listing *all* the software used. The list is not that long and it'd call it fair. But there are obstacles like copyrighted names, trademarks and such stuff. I've tried to google for an example, but found nothing but the [EPSON list](http://support.epson-europe.com/onlineguides/en/px700800series/html_z/oss_2.htm) (which is for a piece of hardware).

Does anyone know an example of software list for a web application? I'm especially curious what's the best solution for Java (run on a computer not owned by me).

Comment: The "Does anyone know an example of software list for a web application?" part of the question is a request for some resource out there.  To answer the question of what you need to do to comply with the licenses you need to also identify what the distribution of the software."  Furthermore, when you start getting into complex questions of multiple licenses, "trademarks and such stuff" it starts veering into the realm where expert legal advice is the only right answer (a lawyer).  However, it is unclear where this question is going and what you need to answer it.

Comment: I voted to close as "unclear what you are asking."  In the future, please resist the temptation to put meta-commentary in your question.  That's not where it belongs; it belongs down here in the comments.  You wouldn't consider it acceptable if someone edited meta commentary into your question, would you?  No, you wouldn't, because it doesn't belong there.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I wouldn't consider it acceptable to put meta-commentary in *others'* question. I also don't consider it acceptable to remove it from others' questions. I'd be OK to remove the first sentence (which I agree is misplaced there), but not so for the following as it also explains why the question is not more detailed.

Comment: The only thing that belongs in a question is *the question.*

Answer (score 1):

Software distribution happens when you make a copy of software and give that copy to someone else for their use. If the software remains under your ownership and control and you give it to someone acting as your agent to carry out your instructions that is not distribution.

You don't have to list everything and you never could. Just acknowledge a few of the biggies.

There are two important factors you did not mention.

1. Do you want to keep your source code private, or are you willing to distribute it?
2. Do you want to make money out of this, or will you compete with someone who does?

The basic breakdown is this. If you make no money out of it and harm no-one then just do your best, acknowledge the work of others and don't worry too much. If you have GPL in the mix you will probably have to distribute your source code (depending on some rather complex rules) but if not, then you can probably keep it private if you want.

If you make money out of your product or services and/or if you may cause damage to someone or compete with someone who does, then you must take competent legal advice. That won't protect you, but it will warn you about the risks and possibly help to mitigate them. You are at risk, even if you don't realise it, and the more money you make the bigger the risk.

Answer (score 0):

The only real "easy" ways to comply with "all" open source licenses is to never distribute your code, or make it accessible by the public.  Absent that, there is no technique that will allow you to ensure compliance with all of the various OSS requirements without understanding them.

Hoverer, you may be overestimating the amount of work it would be to read, understand, and comply with the few licenses that actually affect your project. Just because your software uses another program does not mean that you are deriving from that program, and thus would need to follow its rules.  Your fancy web-app could be written in php, on a Linux 0S, and be designed with an assumption of MySQL and Mozilla Firefox, and yet you wouldn't necessarily be covered by the copyleft rules of any of those projects.  (unless you shipped a pre-made server or something.)